# Vagrant or Docker for Raspbian application

Tags: raspbian, docker, fedora

I have an application which runs on RPi (raspbian). Is there a way to run that application (web application - tornado and flask) on my laptop running Fedora 25? Basically, i want to have the development server on my lappy.

If it is necessary the application is: [Astrobox](https://github.com/AstroPrint/AstroBox])

Comment: I don't believe either of these will work. The issue is that you are trying to run an ARM based app on an x86 architecture. You could run an X86 based vagrant or docker version that supports tornado and flask, but any version you develop that way may work on your development box but not a Pi. This is the classic but it works on my box problem.

Comment: @SteveRobillard so there is no other way for easy development server? I will have to have a RPi and a monitor for the development?

Comment: You can develop on your PC just know that your dev environment and production (pi) will not match. this can lead to issues because of the sometimes subtle differences. You don't need a monitor though you can setup samba to share files. This will let you use the power of your PC and run IDE's etc. and then serve them from the PI and view them on a browser from your PC. You can also use SSH to run any needed command line commands (launch a server, generate code etc.). This is what I do as it lets me use the speed of my PC and run it in a production like environment.

Answer (score 2):

QEMU has an ARM emulator. It's a SW emulator and you should have a powerful Linux box.

I personally use QEMU to run a test suite on raspbian to test a shell script. I didn't try to run a web application. But I would give it a try. I published the steps I executed to create the QEMU image on my Linux desktop [on this page](https://www.linux-tips-and-tricks.de/en/raspberry/310-how-to-emulate-raspberry-pi-on-kvm-2). Hope it helps you to get a QEMU raspbian image up and running very quickly :-)